# How does java recognise a class loader?

Tags: java, classloader

sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader - is the default System Class Loader.

User classes are loaded by this class loader.

e.g.:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
   A a = new A();
   System.out.println(a.getClass().getClassLoader()); 
}
```

returns sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.

Class A is loaded by sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader.loadClass(var1, var2) method. Java triggers it to load this class implicitly.

However, I did not find the loading logic in an aforementioned method.
By its code, it seems to delegate class loading to parent class loader. But in that case parent class loader has to be returned instead of AppClassLoader.

Once again, by this method, the class seems to be not loaded by this class loader, but java returns exactly this one for the user class.

1. Why ?
2. How does it work?

This is decompiled method of sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader:

> ```
> public Class<?> loadClass(String var1, boolean var2) throws ClassNotFoundException {
>     int var3 = var1.lastIndexOf(46);
>     if(var3 != -1) {
>         SecurityManager var4 = System.getSecurityManager();
>         if(var4 != null) {
>             var4.checkPackageAccess(var1.substring(0, var3));
>         }
>     }
>
>     if(this.ucp.knownToNotExist(var1)) {
>         Class var5 = this.findLoadedClass(var1);
>         if(var5 != null) {
>             if(var2) {
>                 this.resolveClass(var5);
>             }
>
>             return var5;
>         } else {
>             throw new ClassNotFoundException(var1);
>         }
>     } else {
>         return super.loadClass(var1, var2);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I still can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: I dont understand your question... But try to look here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/learn-java-the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html maybe it will help you little bit. And about your edit, which partou of this method you dont understand?

Comment: Thank you for provided article. It is good as basic information, but does not answer my question. I do not understand where is the part which is pitched to "Define the class for the VM". This method does not really load the class, but delegates its loading further, to a parent class loader.

Comment: "By its code, it always delegates class loading to parent class loader. But in that case parent class loader has to be returned instead of AppClassLoader." Why do you say that?  It sounds like you've proved that that isn't the case.

Comment: I understand that I am wrong, but I do not understand where and why. This is the question. By theory, it is, but in practice, it is not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But suppose at the top level of the class loader object hierarchy, the class loader ultimately puts `this` in the new class's reference to its class loader. Well, `this` will be really a reference to `AppClassLoader`.

Comment: And check [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/misc/Launcher.java#Launcher.AppClassLoader) for the *real* source code of that class.

Comment: "By its code, it always delegates class loading to parent class loader" - no, it delegates to the superclass: `return super.loadClass(var1, var2);`

Comment: Yes, and by this method java.lang.ClassLoader#loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean):
c = parent.loadClass(name, false); it delegates loading to parent CL, however null is returned. And really, the loading happens here:
 c = findClass(name); 
This is the reason why class A is really loaded by sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader .  Thank you yanus for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is main thread stack trace for your example taken during class `A` loading:

```
  [native] java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1() <= this points to Laucher$AppClassLoader here 
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:764)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-1)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  - locked <0x1f4> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

and then in native code after some preparations class parsing/definition occurs in 
/src/share/vm/classfile/classFileParser.cpp:

```
instanceKlassHandle ClassFileParser::parseClassFile(Symbol* name,
                                                    Handle class_loader,
                                                    Handle protection_domain,
                                                    KlassHandle host_klass,
                                                    GrowableArray<Handle>* cp_patches,
                                                    TempNewSymbol& parsed_name,
                                                    bool verify,
                                                    TRAPS) {
    // ... lots of code here
    this_klass->set_class_loader(class_loader());
    // ... and here
}
```

where class_loader parameter is handle to instance of Laucher$AppClassLoader.
So there is nothing mystical here.